# How to structure javascript test project for team foundation service

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jasmine, azure-devops

I have a collection of javascript files in WebProject-A. I have a set of jasmine spec files in TestWebProject-A. I use the hosted TFS service to run my builds, and everything is set to fail on a test failure.

My spec files reference the js file under test using the reference comment like this:

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
/// <reference path="jasmine/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="..\..\..\WebProject\WebProjectA\App\Controllers.js"/>
```

Note that the ......\ takes the out of the testing project where the spec if defined and in to the real web project.

Locally everything works fine. On TFS build it fails because the test says that the object under test is undefined (pretty sure this is due to pathing)

I can't 'copy' the file using "Add as link" because as far as I understand this only copies it in on compilation. And it's always missing (even locally)

I tried adding a copy statement to the pre-build task like this

```
copy $(solutionDir)\path\to\app\*.js $(solutionDir)\path\to\test\ -y
```

and then changing the reference location. Again this worked locally as expected, but on the build service failed with a -1 result.

Can anyone offer any pointers on how to structure the tests correctly. For the time being I'm going to add the tests to the webproject and block the route to them, but it feels hacky and wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How are the files layed out in the build drop?

Comment: They're like this:
drop/_publishedWebsites/WebProjectA
drop/_publishedWebsites/WebProjectA-Test

The trouble is how do I get the path to work for both environments (local and TFS). I guess I could just add the reference twice in the spec file and have one of them unresolved in each. I also thought that the drop happened after the build

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Matthew Manela the issue is solved. Because of the way I structure my test in the solution directory they end up being moved around in the drop folder of the build.
I added two reference comments, one to work locally and one to work relative to the way files are laid out in the drop folder.
Now it all works as it should locally and during the build. If you want to avoid this duplicate reference pay close attention to where you create your test project, and put it in the same directory as your web project.